# A script that display an image which is in a span in a different page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to display the avatar of a user in a topic on a forum. The avatar is displayed under a span (for example `<span class=avatar><img src=url></span>`) in the page of the user profile (which is for example `http://website.com/?profile=user_id`).
I ask because the user can change his profile picture, and It have to automatic change in my topic too.
Sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: If the target has CORS enabled you can ajax the other page. If not and the name is always the same, like avatar.jpg, then you can just load it. If neither, then you need to grab the html on your server

Comment: Can't you use a webmethod to get the image? Is CORS allowed? Usually isn't a good idea to scrape the page

Comment: CORS isn't allowed, and I can't use a webmethod...